# Selecting multiple columns and send to jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I'm building an web application using Node.js, and I'm getting data from my Mysql database using the following function:

```
function getRobots(robotname, ownerid, callback) {
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM robots WHERE robot_owner_id = ?', ownerid, function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) callback(err, null);
        else 
        callback(null, rows);
    });
}
```

And when the user Logs in I call the function (var x is the user id):

```
        getRobots("robot", x, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {

            console.log("ERROR : ", err);
            } else {
            console.log(data);
            res.render('logged_in', {
            data: data
            });
            }
        });
```

The callback returns me this:

```
[ RowDataPacket {
    robot_id: 1,
    robot_name: 'one',
    robot_status: 1,
    robot_owner_id: 35 },
  RowDataPacket {
    robot_id: 2,
    robot_name: 'ASAS',
    robot_status: 1,
    robot_owner_id: 35 } ]
```

And my question is, how can I separate and retrieve all the columns data, and send to my jade layout?

I would like to do something like this:

```
<ul>
<li>Robot 1 | Id 1</li>
<li>Robot 2 | Id 2</li>
...
```

Thank you.

Comment: So did you try something? What doesn't work for you? Did you check the documentation for loops in Pug? https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html

Comment: this link seems to be what am I looking for, I will try to implement these codes.

Answer (score 0):

In your pug template you need to create a table with an each statement right below the tbody:

```
table
  thead
    tr
      th ID
      th Name
      th Status
      th OwnerID
  tbody
    each robot in data
      tr
        td= robot.id
        td= robot.name
        td= robot.status
        td= robot.owner_id
```